# Thread output listener

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I need to make a thread that start at swing button push and wait for input from rs232, process it and return `String` to my variable. The question is how to do that?

it should be something like that:

```
  String myOutputString = waitForInputThread();
```

Or if its possible in swing panel make something like listener that do something if this `waitForInputThread` send interrupt (for example, if get rs232 input do update a list of items in `JTable`).

Could you give me some clues, tutorials, examples etc ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead implement a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: @Zoyd is rename not easier instead of the retags?

Comment: What do you mean by rename ? Rename what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid blocking the Event Dispatch Thread (which is the thread that updates the GUI), start a new thread to interact with the RS232. The [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class is one option, but you can just as easily use a normal thread.<sup>1</sup> Blocking the EDT causes your GUI to freeze, so it must never be used for lengthy tasks.

Once your result is computed, update the GUI using [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29). This ensures the GUI change occurs on the EDT.

<sup>1</sup> *I tend to find normal threads executed via an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) are better for unit testing (as you can write an `ExecutorService` that immediately executes the `Runnable`, avoiding any nasty thread issues with JUnit).*

Comment: Ok, I've got one thread running all the time reading rs232, but how to   write a listener to thread events ? I want it like that: thread working all the time and when he reads rs232 he passes it like an event. The listener in gui reads this event and do something.